# Getting old geoserver data to new freshly installed geoserver

Tags: file, tomcat, geoserver

I had a working copy of `geoserver 2.3` with my working files but decided to install a bran new `geoserver 2.4` with apache tomcat so I am using `geoserver.war` file. I also had made a copy of my `data_dir` folder cause I had seen that it seemed to have geoserver project I was working on in it.

Now for some reason it does not want to work. I have copied the files into the data directory and it didn't work and I had changed the name of the directory in the `web.xml` file and that did not work.

I'm am not sure what I am missing or if i'm doing something wrong can someone please help.

Comment: I have already tried to follow this
(http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/datadirectory/data-dir-setting.html#data-dir-setting) but that did not seem to work either.

Comment: What does your Tomcat log say? Also a tips, you can edit your question with additional information rather than adding a comment. :)

Comment: The tom stdeout log seems to be picking up from my stand alone geoserver and the war file that is there. and the tomcat stderr just says starting the server.